# accessing a non model field in pre_save signal

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to add a simple non model field in a django form:

```
<input type="text" name="setupwork" value=""/>
```

then access its value on the pre_save signal.

Is there any way to do so, I looked into pre_save parameters: sender, instance, using, **kwargs but couldn't find that field.

Comment: `pre_save` is a signal for a model, not a form, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to have a 'honeypot' field, that is a hidden form field that is supposed to always be empty (humans would not fill it). So I need to check anytime a form is submitted that this field is indeed empty. There is a module for that but it causes issue with django-allauth so I try to do simple custom implementation. Is there a signal for forms ?

Comment: So are you trying to use a model form or are you just trying to include a hidden field in your form?

Comment: just trying to include a hidden field in the form without any tie to model. Then I need to intercept form before it is submitted to check it. I wanted to use signal because I don't have access to code of some module I use, so it would have been a global solution.

Comment: If you don't have access to the view or form, you can't pass the value to the pre_save signal. If you do have access, you could set it as an instance attribute, but then you're better off performing the check in the view or form anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you just want to add to your form a hidden field, which you can then check if that has anything in it

```
class MyForm(Form):
    my_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean_my_field(self):

        data = self.cleaned_data['my_field']

        if data:
             raise ValidationError()
        return data
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't there a more global way to do so: I don't have access to model and view code of some third party modules

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I was thinking that I could access FORM from pre_save signal. As explained above by contributors, this is NOT the case. You can only access model data with relation to form. So in my case, a field added only to the html form would now show up in pre_save instance.

I resolved the problem by creating a custom middleware that would trigger on any POST method, and check the presence and content of the decoupled html form field.